# Is it possible to set different brightness level to each part of screen/activity?

Tags: android, screen, partial, brightness

I know how to change brightness of entire window:

```
float brightness = 255;
brightness = brightness / (float) 255;
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

but is it possible to set brightness to different parts of the screen?

I want reach something like this:

[image: img]

or this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android API doesn't provide any means to achieve that(I've head a similar problem. Didn't find any solution).

Answer (score 0):

There are no Api's to do that like GareginSargsyan said.

However,

By Using a grey or black tint (create one in photoshop or some application) wherever you want the screen to be dimmer than the other (this image should be a see through one like a .png image). call this image(coloured tint) in your program through xml or java.

Try it..